# Show next div on scroll Down/Up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

First I use an library to animate going from `#one` to `#two` with this code:

```
$(function() {
    $('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

my html is:

```
<div id="indicators">

    <a href="#one" class="btn page-scroll" style="border-radius: 50%;"><i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
    <a href="#two" class="btn page-scroll"><i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
    <a href="#three" class="btn page-scroll"><i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
    </div>
```

so now when I click on some indicator (circle icon) send me with animation to there div but what I want to do now is when user have focus on some div and when scroll down to show to them new #id with animation...

etc. user have focus in #two and when scroll down a little to show them `#three` with animation ...

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (st > lastScrollTop){

//down
   } else {
     // up
   }
   lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

How to find on which div user make scroll? Also what I need to do is like on this website: http://hotelgene.com/

Comment: looks like they have used this plugin: http://www.alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/

Comment: Yes thanks... thats is correct answer!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not the question about how to find user is looking at which page.
Just make sure no matter how many times user scrolling, the scroll-height always keep in the right position. You just listen to the mouse event, if user scroll down too much, they will scroll up again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
        var y = $(this).scrollTop();
        //200 is the total height of divs before div with animation enters viewport
        if (y > 200) {
            $('.three').addClass("animation");
        }   else {
            $('.three').removeClass("animation");
        }
```

```css
.one {
  height: 100px;
  }
.two {
  height: 100px;
  }
.three {
  height: 100px;
  }
.animation {
  transition: all ease-in 0.2s /* or any transition you choose*/
    }
```

```html
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
<div class="three"></div>
```

This should help you out.